# Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262 :

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I have just started to use docker. I have installed `alpine` image for testing docker workflow but after running

```
docker run alpine ls -l
```

I am getting this following error

> Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262:
>   starting container process caused "exec: \"ls-l\": executable file not
>   found in $PATH".

I have installed **Docker Desktop for Windows** in Windows 10.

Answer (score 5):

The last argument to `docker run` must be the name of an executable. `ls` is a command implemented by the shell, but not an executable in itself, hence the error you see. You have to tell docker to run `ls` in the context of a particular shell. E.g.

```
$ docker run alpine sh -c 'ls -l'
total 52
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Oct 25 22:05 bin
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root           340 Nov 15 22:45 dev
drwxr-xr-x   14 root     root          4096 Nov 15 22:45 etc
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can confirm this works. Also, just running in -it mode appeared to work for me too.